# Python Cyclic Dependency with Async I/O

Tags: python, python-3.x, client-server, python-asyncio

While looking over the new features in Python 3.x, I was intrigued by the asyncio library being added. After looking at the reference documentation, I decided to play around with it a little bit.

This worked well until I tried to make it work for multiple clients, and keep a list of all active/connected clients. This introduced a cyclic dependency between the server class and the session class.

Now, I've tried a few different ways to resolve this; however, there doesn't appear to be any way for me to get at this data directly from the server class through any method/functional call.

While I have been able to workaround this by using a "lazy" import, it seems like this my be indicative of either a poor design, a lack of understanding of the library itself, or a combination of both.

Code wise, I have a small sample put together. Am I missing an obvious solution here, or does my organization need to change to better support the functionality provided by the asyncio library?

__main__.py:

```py
from network.server import Server

def main(args=None):
    s = Server()

    try:
        s.run()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

    s.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

server.py:

```py
import asyncio

from network.session import Session

class Server:

    sessionList = []

    def __init__(self):    
        self.handler = None

        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

        self.coro = self.loop.create_server(Session, 'localhost', 1234)

    def run(self):
        self.handler = self.loop.run_until_complete(self.coro)

        print('Server Running On: {}'.format(self.handler.sockets[0].getsockname()))

        self.loop.run_forever()

    def close(self):
        self.handler.close()

        self.loop.run_until_complete(self.handler.wait_closed())

        self.loop.close()

    @staticmethod
    def add_session(session):
        Server.sessionList.append(session)

    @staticmethod
    def del_session(session):
        Server.sessionList.remove(session)
```

session.py:

```py
import asyncio

class Session(asyncio.Protocol):

    def __init__(self):
        from network.server import Server

        self._transport = None

        Server.add_session(self)

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self._transport = transport

        self._transport.write('Echo Server Example\r\n\r\n'.encode())

    def data_received(self, data):
        self._transport.write(data)

    def eof_received(self):
        self._transport.close()

    def connection_lost(self, exc):
        from network.server import Server

        Server.del_session(self)

        if exc is not None:
            self._transport.close()
```

Comment: Have a look at aiohttp for server / client handling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may pass `server` instance into `Session` constructor:

```py
self.loop.create_server(lambda: Session(self), 'localhost', 1234)
```

Storing `sessionList` as global object is not the best practice.

I recommend saving it as `self.sessionList = []` in `Server.__init__` and converting both `add_session` and `del_session` from `staticmethod` into regular methods.

Comment: It looks like your suggestion works as expected, so I have flagged the response as the accepted answer.  One thing I did note from this:  it prevents type hinting on the `Server` parameter in the `Session` constructor; however, I believe this is resolved with Python 3.5 via PEP 0484's forward declaration for hinting.